# Select with double duplicates

Tags: mysql

Here is an example

```
a   b
--------
1   10
1   10
2   20
2   20
3   20
3   20
4   NULL
5   NULL
```

I want this in a mySQL query :

```
a       b 
------------
1       10
2 or 3  20
4       NULL
5       NULL
```

In other words : the set of elements where (there is no duplicates on `a` and (there is no duplicates on `b` or `b` is `NULL`)).

I try the

- `SELECT DISTINCT(a), b`, but I have 2 rows with b = 20
- `SELECT a, DISTINCT(b)`, but I have duplicates on column a and the 2 `NULL` values are merged.
- `GROUP BY a` or `GROUP BY b`, equal as the 2 previous queries.

Does anyone have an idea for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(a) a, b
FROM   table1
WHERE  b IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY b
UNION
SELECT a, b
FROM   table1
WHERE  b IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79be3/5)

---

give this a try,

```
SELECT MIN(a) a, b
FROM   table1
GROUP  BY COALESCE(b, RAND())
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79be3/7)

Comment: Both won't give back the `3` OP asked for, though I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be possible anyway.

Comment: @Aquillo He wanted `2` _or_ `3` returned, this returns `2`.

Comment: @JW웃 +1 for your fiddles :)

Comment: last one works, and what i was thinking except i used `ifnull`. anyone know which would be "cheaper": http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79be3/17

Comment: @gillyspy right. `IFNULL` is far more better because you have only one option to replace `NULL` :)

Comment: Whow, juste love the last example you left. The mix with COALESCE and RAND is so beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be faster

```
SELECT MIN(a) a, b
  FROM table1
GROUP by IF( b is null, a, b);
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79be3/25)**

Comment: see the result of this query with new set of records: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12d0/1